# The provider 'vmware_desktop' could not be found on macos m1

Tags: vagrant, apple-m1, vmware-fusion

- install both `vagrant` and `vmware` via homebrew

```
brew install --cask vagrant
brew install --cask vmware-fusion
```

- verify that everything is installed

```
➜  ~ vmrun -T ws list

Total running VMs: 0
➜  ~ vagrant -v

Vagrant 2.3.0
```

- set the `default provider` as `vmware_desktop` in my .zshrc (and "sourced" it)

```bash
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=vmware_desktop
```

- initialize a folder and add a box following [official get started](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/vagrant/getting-started)

```
vagrant init hashicorp/bionic64
vagrant box add hashicorp/bionic64
```

and select the option `3) vmware_desktop`

- finally run `vagrant up` from the initialised folder and observe the error

```
The provider 'vmware_desktop' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.

Vagrant knows about the following providers: docker, hyperv, virtualbox
```

did I make some mistake in the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss to [install the Vagrant VMWare plugin](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/vmware/installation)

First you need to install [Vagrant VMware Utility](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads/vmware)

Then you can install the plugin

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop
```

Comment: the error is solved, getting some other error... progress I guess

Comment: ... indeed, one step at a time. hope you get some answers from previous questions here

Comment: I asked a question in the `Vagrant Community Forum` this time, lets's see how it goes, thanks for your help <3

Comment: From the tag: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.